# How to access a variable using its name as a string

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, class-attributes

I was thinking of using a plist file to configure how I would upload a form to my server but then I realised I don't know how I could do one crucial part of this or even if this is possible since you can't dynamically declare variables with swift.

Basically I was thinking of using a dictionary like this

form:

- property_name: backend_name

and then in my form upload method I would do something that would look like this

```
formValues: [String:String] = [:]
form.forEach { (property_name, backend_name) in
  let value = someController[property_name] // to do the equivalent of someController.property_name
  formValues[backend_name] = value
}
// ...
formValues.forEach { (backend_name, value) in
  multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: backend_name)
}
```

the problem is I don't know how to this part

```
let value = someController[property_name]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're trying to solve is serializing your data for a server. I don't know whether the approach you're trying is *possible* in Swift, but it's definitely not the right one. If you're using Swift 4, you could create `Codable` model objects, so this serialization will be all under the hood. Otherwise, you'll most likely need to create this `[String: Any]` manually.

[Using Codable to serialize/deserialize objects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Comment: So you're saying that you can't access a class property dynamically ? it would probably be for the same reason you can't create a class property dynamically either Edit: I'm using swift 3.2

Comment: I'm not sure whether you could possibly achieve what you want with `KeyPath`s. They also got a revamp in Swift 4 so they're more powerful. Another thing to possibly look into.

Comment: But yeah, in summary, Swift has a strong type system and likes knowing the types of everything. Can make problems like this difficult.

Comment: I took some time to mark the answer, sorry, completely forgot and although I found how to do it how I imagined it I chose to go with serializing my data

Answer (score 0):

I found how I could do it.

```
formValues: [String:String] = [:]
form.forEach { (property_name, backend_name) in
  let value = Mirror(reflecting: someController).children.filter({ (child) -> Bool in
    return child.label == property_name
}).first!.value as! String
  formValues[backend_name] = value
}
// ...
formValues.forEach { (backend_name, value) in
  multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: backend_name)
}
```

I know this is unoptimised since I recreate a mirror each cycle but it's for demonstration purposes